# Make: how to replace character within a make variable?

Tags: makefile

I have a variable such :

```
export ITEM={countryname}
```

this can be :

```
   "Albania", 
   "United States"   // with space
   "Fs. Artic Land"  // dot
   "Korea (Rep. Of)" // braket
   "Cote d'Ivoir"    // '
```

This variable `$(ITEM)` is passed to other commands, some needing is as it (fine, I will use `$(ITEM)`), some MUST HAVE characters replacements, by example, to go with `mkdir -p ../folder/{countryname}` :

```
   "Albania"          // => Albania
   "United States"    // => United_States
   "Fs. Artic Land"   // => Fs\._Artic_Land
   "Korea (Rep. Of)"  // => Korea_\(Rep\._Of\)
   "Cote d'Ivoire"    // => Cote_d\'Ivoire
```

So I need a new make variable such

```
export ITEM={countryname}
export escaped_ITEM=$(ITEM).processed_to_be_fine
```

**How should I do this characters replacements within my makefile ?** (to keep things simple and not have to do an external script). I was thinking to use some transclude `tr` or something.

Note: working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are the contents of that variable literally that string (with the `[` and quotes and commas but presumably not with the `//` comments)? You don't need to escape any of those strings if you use them within quotes at the shell level (i.e. `mkdir -p "Cote d'Ivoire"` and `mkdir -p "Korea (Rep. Of)"` work just fine.)

Comment: My make run `mkdir -p Cote d'Ivoire` which doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, notice how you didn't quote that directory name and I did. That's important.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Ok, seems transclusion is not need for my case. My MAKE command should be corrected from `mkdir -p /output/$(ITEM)` into  `mkdir -p /output/"$(ITEM)"`, then it works. Etan, could you add this answer so I +1 an other readers may see it ? I will then validate a substitution answer since it answer more to the question as I wrote it, but I will implement simple your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid your makefile will be very tricky or possibly broken if you use these as file names that Make needs to handle. Getting them to work in the shell was the easy part.

Comment: For the record wrapping arbitrary strings in double quotes is not safe. All sorts of things will break that (e.g. `ITEM=foo $(touch /tmp/busted) bar`, etc.). But if you know your input it works.

Comment: @tripleee Has a point. make will not be able to do anything at all sane with files with spaces in them. It just cannot understand that.

Comment: I also worry about lower end usages of my output files, that's why I first went for substitution of ` ` into `_`. Given your late feedbacks, seems better that I indeed push up to substitution.

Comment: If you are more familiar with it, it should be possible to use something such `export escaped_ITEM=echo "$(ITEM2)" | tr " " "_"` and then call `$(escaped_ITEM)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `subst` function in GNU Make to perform substitutions.

```
escaped_ITEM := $(subst $e ,_,$(ITEM))
```

(where `$e` is an undefined or empty variable; thanks to @EtanReisner for pointing it out).

You will need one `subst` for each separate substitution, though.

If at all possible, I would advise against this, however -- use single, machine-readable tokens for file names, and map them to human readable only as the very last step. That's also much easier in your makefile:

```
human_readable_us=United States
human_readable_kr=Korea (Rep. of)
human_readable_ci=Côte d'Ivoire
human_readable_tf=FS. Antarctic Lands

stuff:
        echo "$(human_readable_$(ITEM))"
```

Comment: That `subst` needs to be `$(subst $e ,_,$(ITEM))` (where `$e` is just any empty variable, doesn't even need to be define) or make doesn't see the space there.

Comment: I was thinking backslash but didn't get to test anything. This will work anyway; thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about switching to machine readable keys. I will see if it's possible with my data.

Answer (score 2):

Given the input simply "quoting" the country "names" when using them in the shell will work fine (for the few shown here) but double quoting arbitrary strings is not safe as any number of things can still evaluate inside double quotes (and with the way make operates even double quotes themselves in the string will cause problems).

If you need to pass "random" strings to the shell their is only one safe way to do that: replace every instance of `'` (a single quote) in the string with `'\''` and then wrap the string in `'` (single quotes). (Depending on the consumer of the string replacing each `'` with `\047` can also work.)